# .Net1 MenuItem vs. .Net2 ToolStripMenuItem -> Select Event

Tags: c#, .net

In .NET 1.1 I used a `MenuItem` select event, but for the `ToolStripMenuItem`s this event doesn't seem to exist. What is the alternative?

**Edit:** `MouseEnter` or `MouseHover` doesn't catch menu selection via the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ToolStripMenuItem.MouseEnter` or `ToolStripMenuItem.MouseHover`

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you can't use MenuItem? From the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.aspx):

> Although ToolStripMenuItem replaces and adds functionality to the MenuItem control of previous versions, MenuItem is retained for both backward compatibility and future use if you choose.

So MenuItem will continue to be supported in the future...